# How to convert DatetimeIndex to tuple?

Tags: python, datetimeindex

I have a list as below. How can I convert to tuple format?
Please somebody help me!

[As-is]

```
DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-01 00:00:44'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

[To-be]

```
(2000,01,01)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

dt = pd.DatetimeIndex([
    '2000-01-01 00:00:44',
    '2011-02-03 00:00:40'
], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

print(list(zip(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day)))
```

prints

```
[(2000, 1, 1), (2011, 2, 3)]
```